# Jmeter timer positioning

Tags: timer, jmeter

Can anyone tell me if there's any difference between:

- using a timer between two http requests
- using the same timer as a child for the second http request?

The only difference I see is that the script is better structured and easier to read. The delay between requests seems to be identical in the case of both transaction_controllers.

See attachment for a more explanatory information:

[image: test-plan]

Answer (score 1):

Timer positioning will affect your test plan.

When the timer is placed in the same level with other requests, it is applied to all the HTTP requests and child requests of controllers in the same level. All the requests will be delayed by the time mentioned in the timer.

```
Request 1
Request 2
Request 3
Controller
    Request 4
    Request 5
Timer 1
```

When we add the timer as a child of a Request as given below, delay is applied only to the particular request.

```
Request 1
Request 2
Request 3
    Timer 1
Controller
    Request 4
    Request 5
```

> You have mentioned that you do not see any difference in both cases.  I am not sure if your timer has the default 300 ms delay.  Try to add more requests I had given and update the time delay as 5000 ms to understand better how it works.

Comment: You are correct, thank you, I retested with more care and I confirm that, practically wherever you might put the timer in the script (if at same level with the requests), the delay is applied to all the requests.